# Hybrid mobile apps

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

So what I'm looking for is a JavaScript **interpreter** for both iOS and Android. I don't want to compile the code because the JavaScript code won't be available until in the runtime. Let me explain better:

Basically, what I'm looking for is a hybrid application mainly written in Obj-C and Java for iOS and Android, respectively, and
using tools like NativeScript, Titanium, etc, for only a small part of the app. I know it's not possible using NativeScript (I asked) but I'm not sure about the Titanium. Is it possible to have one page in the app using Titanium (or any other tools that you know) and leave the rest to the native code?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you can do that with Titanium, sorry.